# Sleeping display using IOKit on Lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, sleep, iokit

I have the following code that is suppose to sleep the display on a Mac. I've tried it on Lion but it doesn't seem to do anything. I tested the code by creating a barebones window Mac app with a button in the window and an IBAction method. When the button is pressed, the function below is called, however nothing happens.

Any suggestions as to why it doesn't work?

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>

int display_sleep(void)
{
    io_registry_entry_t reg = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/IOResources/IODisplayWrangler");

    if (reg) 
    {
        IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty(reg, CFSTR("IORequestIdle"), kCFBooleanTrue);
        IOObjectRelease(reg);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```